# IntelliJ IDEA Android emulator installs multiple copies of the app

Tags: android, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Each time I launch my Android app in IntelliJ IDEA's virtual emulator, it seems to install a new copy of the app. I have 4 copies of the same app in the emulated phone now. :/ Is there a way I can force the emulator to install over the previous installation each time I run it, instead of installing a new copy of the app?

Edit: I've found that selecting 'wipe user data' works in a pinch. I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution though, as wiping clears out everything (including files on the phone, user logins etc) which isn't always what I want.

Comment: Are you trying to create App shortcut ? Or is it actually installing same app with multiple copies ?

Comment: It actually installed multiple copies of the same app